# How to read dropdown select with cell values in a datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, dropdown

I have this Jquery function to read and return data from a Jquery datatable. 
I can read cell values ok but when it comes to drop-down it return entire option list. i tried few different ways but still couldn't get it right.  how can i modify it to get selected values only in the last column with other cell values in other columns.

My table

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th></th>
            <th name="nn">Column0</th>
            <th name="nm">Column1</th>
            <th name="no">Column2</th>
            <th name="np">Column3</th>
            <th name="nq">Column4</th>
            <th>select</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

my jquery function. i cannot use table stringfy for some reason.

```
function tableToJSON(tblObj) {
    var data = [];
    var $headers = $(tblObj).find("th");
    var $rows = $(tblObj).find("tbody tr").each(function (index) {
        $cells = $(this).find("td");

        data[index] = {};
        $cells.each(function (cellIndex) {

            if ($(this).$headers == "select") {
                //data[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
                data[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).find('select').val();

            }

            else 
            {
                data[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
            }


        });

    });
    return data;
}
```

Thank You

Comment: You nee to show us the html for a typical row. (and your `if ($(this).$headers == "select") {` makes no sense and the code inside it will never be executed)

Answer (score 0):

You have $.each inside other $.each function and `$(this)` is parent element
`if ($(this).$headers == "select") {`
try add some variable before second $.each